# Jenkins Shell script, replace "/" with "_", fails with Bad substitution

Tags: jenkins, sh

I have a Jenkins job with 1 string parameter ($BRANCH) default set to "branch/stage/feature".
The single build step is to Execute Shell..

```
set +x
echo ${BRANCH////_}
```

It fails with 'Bad substitution'

I'm trying to replace all the foreward slashes with underscores and save it to a new string.

Comment: Probably Jenkins runs `sh`, not Bash.

Comment: Tangentially, see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Running in bash works
I added #!/bin/bash to the top of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
echo ${BRANCH////_}
```